# StreamingOutput analogue in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, streaming, jax-rs

Is there any analogue of JAX-RS's [`StreamingOutput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html) in Spring MVC? My original task is to free up a servicing thread from writing a large response.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to return an instance of [`InputStreamResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html), [as exemplified by Sergey Petunin](http://forketyfork.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-return-file-stream-or-classpath.html):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stream", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Resource getStream() {
    String string = "Hello World!";
    // acquiring the stream
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes());
    // counting the length of data
    final long contentLength = string.length();
    return new InputStreamResource(stream){
        @Override
        public long contentLength() throws IOException {
            return contentLength;
        }
    };
}
```